# Появление картинки при клике через определённое время - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ссылка например:

```
<a class="show" href="#">показать</a>
```

при нажатии через 3 секунд должно плавно показать изображение:

```
<img id="photo" src="screen.jpg">
```

Написал вот так но не работает:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.show').click(
setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('photo').style.display = 'block';
}, 3000);
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('.show').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#photo').show();
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```